# MQ receive waiting seconds

Tags: java, jms, ibm-mq

I am new to MQ and as per my requirement i need to put 120 seconds in the Receive method to wait message and I written Java Jms standalone application.

is it below line correct.

Message message = queueReceiver.receive(120 * 1000);

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Yes. The following link has more information on it
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_9.1.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q032260_.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: Yes

Long answer:

From the documentation [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/jms/MessageConsumer.html#receive(long))

> Parameters:
>       timeout - the timeout value (in milliseconds)

There are 120000 milliseconds in 120 seconds. So your maths of 120 * 1000 checks out.